# Can Greater and Superior Resistance be made permanent?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, permanency

From the Spell Compendium, *Resistance, Greater* reads:

> This spell functions like resistance (PH 272), except as noted here. You grant the subject a +3 resistance bonus on saves.

*Resistance, Superior* is similar, but for +6.

Since the spell *Resistance* says it can be made permanent with *Permanency*, does that mean these spells can also be made permanent with *Permanency*? Their text apparently allows it, but *Permanency* does not appear to be updated to allow it.

Comment: When you say "but Permanency does not appear to be updated to allow it." are there spells from the SC it does?  I am just curious because I assumed nothing was updated, so was surprised by your note.

Comment: @joedragons Permanency explains the cost of making various spells permanent. That chart is not updated for these new spells. So you could either interpret it as "500 xp for permanent +6 resistance bonus" or permanency would need an update to explain the cost. This is assuming, of course, that these spells are supported by permanency.

Comment: Cool thanks.  What I was trying to infer/clarify is I feel that's the same for all spells in SC not just this one.  The different of course is that this references an existing spell just the "lesser" option.

Answer (score 1):

## Maybe

Ultimately, this comes down to whether one interprets 'functions like [X]' as letting a spell count as that thing or not.  The rules are unclear on that topic and both interpretations have problems:

If "Functions like [X]" is sufficient to make a spell count as 'X', then you would use the *resistance* line in the permanency spell.  This interpretation causes problems because some spells were written without awareness of other special interactions with the spells they emulate, or without awareness of spells that emulate spells they give special interactions to.  This lets people use unusual spell interactions to accomplish esoteric results, which may be undesirable.

If functioning as a given spell doesn't entail counting as that spell, then *permanency* can't affect these spells using *resistance*'s line (though of course it may be able to otherwise do so). This interpretation causes problems because some spells were written with the understanding that they would count as the spells they say they emulate, and thus perform weirdly with this interpretation. While in theory the unexpected behavior could have similar results to the other interpretation, this interpretation in practice results in the badly affected spells failing to accomplish much of anything, including failing to do things they are clearly intended to do, rather than enabling much in the way of exploits.